# An entire function satisfying $|f(z)|\le |z| |x| $ on $\mathbb{C}$ is identically zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function satisfying $|f(z)|\le|z||x|$ where $x=\text{real part of }z$.
Then prove that $f(z)=0$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$

I am able to prove that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. I need to prove that all derivatives vanish at 0. How do I prove that? Help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hypothesis implies that $|f(z)| = 0$ (and hence $f(z) = 0$) for all pure imaginary $z$.  Since the imaginary axis is a set with a limit point, it follows by analytic continuation that $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Identity theorem. Elegant.